# are sum and difference square of two iid standard normal random variables independent?

Tags: probability

Let $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ be two independent standard normal random variables. define  $U=Y_1+Y_2, V=(Y_1-Y_2)^2$ are $U,V$ independent?

my thoughts: generating function of $X$ is defined as $G_X(s)=E(s^X)$ and so if two random variables are independent then generating function of the sum if product of generating fucntions. So consider $U+V= Y_1+Y_2+Y_1^2-Y_1Y_2+Y_2^2$ and $G_{U+V}(s)=E(s^{Y_1}s^{Y_2}s^{{Y_1}^2}s^{-Y_1Y_2}s^{Y_2^2})$ then what?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The joint pdf of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ is given by
$$
f(y_1,y_2) = \frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{y_1^2 + y_2^2}{2}}. 
$$
We now apply the transformation $u = y_1-y_2$ and $v = y_1 + y_2$ then $y_1 = \frac{1}{2}(v+u)$ and $y_2 = \frac{1}{2}(v-u)$. We get for the Jacobian
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} \\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}
\end{bmatrix} = \frac{1}{2}.
$$
Rewrite the pdf as 
\begin{align}
f(y_1,y_2) &= \frac{1}{4\pi}e^{-\frac{1}{8}\left((v+u)^2 + (v-u)^2\right)} = \frac{1}{4\pi}e^{-\frac{1}{4}\left(u^2 + v^2\right)} \\ 
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{2}}e^{-\frac{u^2}{4}}\times\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{2}}e^{-\frac{v^2}{4}}.
\end{align}
Since the pdf splits we conclude that $Y_1-Y_2$ and $Y_1+Y_2$ are independent.

Comment: wow! Thank you sir, so I need to think of the random variable as a measurable function from $R \to R$. Then the join pdf is also a measurable function from $R^2 \to R$. Now because the way we defined u and v, we can write the joint pdf as a function of u and v. then I'm lost. I don't understand what does pdf slit means. And how we are using the jacobian?

Comment: Note that $U$ and $V$ are independent if and only if their joint pdf is a product of their marginal pdfs. In the answer I derived their joint pdf which can be rewritten as a product of functions that depend solely on $u$ or $v$. Hence, it follows that they are independent. The Jacobian is there, because the transformed pdf still has to integrate to one over the new domain.